# Нужно ли здесь использовать float?

Tags: html, css

Посоветуйте, как правильно сверстать такой сайт, приведённый на рисунке?
Интересует вопрос, нужно ли применять здесь float для блоков в шапке и вообще по всему сайту?
т.е. там где логотип, телефон, кнопка перезвонить, корзина, они должны обтекать с помощью float, или тут правильней применить flex?
Также и по контенту и выравнивание товаров интересует, что тут применять: float или flex ? Как расположить контейнеры aside и content ?
Можно ли сделать такой сайт полностью на flex?  и правильно ли будет такое решение?
Также нужно предусмотреть адаптив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос. 
Последний раз я пробовала верстать прямо полностью на флексах где-то полгода назад, и тогда по кроссбраузерности они себя показали так себе. 
И, насколько я поняла, если нужно поддерживать IE, то от флексов стоит воздержаться, по-крайней мере не делать на них полностью весь шаблон. И тестить, часть свойств может косячно работать.

Остальное - дело вкуса и момента.

Я обычно комбинирую inline-box и float. Что из них лучше выбрать - вопрос контекста.

Например, адаптивный сайт. Лого должно быть выровнено четко по левому краю на декстопе, а корзина - по правому краю (по ширине контента). Между ними - строго по центру идет меню сайта с n-м кол-вом пунктов, причем со временем их может становиться больше или меньше. 
А на планшете лого и корзина уходят вверх, тогда как меню опускается ниже.
Тут будет логично выравнивать меню и корзину через float (по правому и левому краю соответственно), менюхе задавать display: inline-block, а всей шапке в целом text-align:center.

Или, использовать флексы, если мы не боимся проблем в IE.

Вот очень крутой пример витрины магазина на флексах.
http://html.innova-media.ru/product_list/index.html

Если собираемся поддерживать все, еще дышащие почему-то, браузеры, то такого типа витрину хорошо верстать на инлайн-блоках. С выравниваниями по ширине-высоте и text-align для родительского контейнера, для адаптивного решения это более выгодное и гибкое решение, нежели использование float.

Одним словом - ответ на Ваш вопрос - комбинировать решения, в зависимости от задачи блоков и их поведении при адаптации. В идеале еще подумать о будущем сайта, например, что если добавится еще пункт меню, что если контента aside станет меньше/больше, это поможет лучше сориентироваться в выборе способа позиционирования.

Comment: Ссылки на примеры в ответах почти бесполезны. Пройдет полгода, сайт полностью поменяется или вообще магазин закроется — ссылка потеряет смысл.

Comment: Это правда. Но то же самое можно сказать про ссылки на всевозможные статьи (даже хабр, пропадают оттуда демо, скрины и т.д.), примерчики на codepen и прочее. Но тут ссылка - не руководство к действию, а иллюстрация. Умрет, достаточно погуглить примеры. Кроме того, через полгода мой ответ может быть в принципе уже не актуальным =) Вот тут переменные в css появляются.. А может мы все будем на гридах уже делать)

Comment: Кстати! Это не магазин, это учебный пример, сделанный автором к какой-то из его статей. Там не настоящие товары, а демонстрация. Так что как раз он может прожить гораздо дольше) Есть вкладка "адаптивная сетка", например, там же.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую ознакомиться с сеткой Bootstrap и взять на вооружение display: inline-block